# 960 grid overlapping div's

Tags: css, 960.gs

I would to create something like this using the 960 grid, is it possible using the framework or do i have to do some custom work?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

960.gs and other CSS Frameworks use the padding and margins, all you have to do is to override them

this is the normal code

```
<div class="span-18">
    <div class="span-4 last">
    </div>
</div>
```

use something like

```
<div class="span-18 cut-margin">
    <div class="span-4 last cut-margin">
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.cut-margin { margin-right: 0 !important; }
```

and set the new width of your elements to the element + the margin/padding you are using.

You can always create your own `bigspan` classes, for example:

```
.bigspan-4 { width: 475px; margin-right: 0px; }
.bigspan-18 { width: 715px; margin-right: 0px; }
```

and

```
<div class="bigspan-18">
    <div class="bigspan-4">
    </div>
</div>
```

---

remember that you can always [design your onw grid](http://www.spry-soft.com/grids/)